# Searchable dropdown in flutter taking extra space after getting selected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a flutter application which contains searchable dropdown in it. The searchable dropdown when it is not selected looks good but when any item from it is selected then it takes up extra space within the dropdown. How to remove the extra space in it?

I am using this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

[image]

Above is the image of how the extra space is taken in the searchable dropdown.

Following is the code for searchable dropdown:

```
SearchableDropdown.single(
                              items: snapshot.data
                                  ? _issuingBloc[index]
                                      .countryname
                                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                          (value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 26),
                                                child: Text(value,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                              )))
                                      .toList()
                                  : null,
                              underline: Container(),
                              value: dropdownsnapshot.data == ""
                                  ? ""
                                  : dropdownsnapshot.data,
                              hint: Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                child: Text("Select Issuing Authority"),
                              ),
                              searchHint: "Select Issuing Authority",
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                print(value);
                                issuingvalue[index] = value;
                                
                              },
                              isExpanded: true,
                            );
```

I want the searchable dropdown to look just as the textbook below it? Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: are you using some package of dropdown searchable?, if so, please mention it

Comment: yes, @RajaEhtisham . Added the package name as well

Comment: visit this issue it will help you https://github.com/lcuis/search_choices/issues/40

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SearchableDropdown.single(
                          items: snapshot.data
                              ? _issuingBloc[index]
                                  .countryname
                                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: value,
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 26),
                                            child: Text(value,
                                                overflow:
                                                    TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                          )))
                                  .toList()
                              : null,
                          underline: Container(),
                          value: dropdownsnapshot.data == ""
                              ? ""
                              : dropdownsnapshot.data,
                          hint: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                            child: Text("Select Issuing Authority"),
                          ),
                          searchHint: "Select Issuing Authority",
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            print(value);
                            issuingvalue[index] = value;
                            
                          },
                          isExpanded: false,// You just need to change is expanded to false
                        );
```

Initially `isExpanded` is `false` and you have set to `true` just change to `false`  or you can remove the `isExpanded` for [more info](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Comment: Won't make any difference as isExpanded is for width expansion not height expansion.